# Join Irreducible elements in Finite Lattice.

Tags: lattice-orders

If $ L $ is a finite lattice then how can we show that each element is of the form $ a_1\vee a_2\vee a_3...\vee a_k$ where each $ a_i$ is a join-irreducible element.

Comment: Hint: in a finite lattice, every nonempty subset has a minimal element. If there are any elements in $\mathcal L$ which is not a sum of join-irreducible elements, there is a minimal such element. Can you get a contradiction from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By contradiction.  Suppose that some element isn't of that form.  Then you can construct an infinite descending chain.

Start with an element which is not the join of the join-irreducible elements beneath it. Then it itself cannot be join-irreducible, so you can express it as the join of two other elements.

You should be able to take it from there.